# Any open-source to animate 2D materials in 3D. (e.g. van der Waals heterostructures, 2D crystal layers etc.)

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, material-science, software, nanoscience

I want to model different 2D nano-structures, layered materials in 3D (animated version). Is there any open source where I can build these structures?

[image: Like this]

Comment: If you want to model from like `scratch` then I would suggest Blender with cutting edge animation and modelling capabilities. Its also open source . Mind it thought that modelling in 3D is extremely time consuming

Comment: Have you heard about [Visual python library](https://vpython.org/) in python ! It has a number of ways to create objects in 3D and also animate them. It is, of course, open source!